# How to parse nested JSON file with different names in python

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

I have a one long line of JSON file that has a bunch of different parameter names. Here is a small portion of it from the beginning.

```
{
    "chrome - amazon.com": {
        "id": "XXXX",
        "name": "Chrome - amazon.com",
        "test_url": "http://amazon.com",
        "division_id": "####",
        "product_id": "####",
        "status": {
            "id": 0,
            "name": "Active"
        },
        "type": {
            "id": 0,
            "name": "Web"
        },
        "monitors": [
            {
                "id": "##",
                "name": "Chrome"
            }
        ],
        "change_date": "8/26/2019 3:30:43 PM"
    },
    "chrome - apple.com": {
        "id": "####",
        "name": "Chrome - apple.com"
    }
}
```

This is what I got when I converted to a CSV file after I wrote this code:

```
df = pd.json_normalize(data)
df.to_csv('testDetail3.csv', index=False)
```

[image]

The "monitors" column is not parsed out and I don't know how I can parse out the "monitors" column when there are various different names. For instance, I will have another "chrome - apple.com.monitors" column that is not parsed and there are a lot more other "names.monitors"

Answer (score 0):

The "monitors" column refers to an array not an object or a number and so on. So this column isn't parsed out.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).